# Sorting a list in order of highest to lowest

Tags: python

Hi there new to python here, so recently I was learning how to code and I encountered this problem.

```
myfile = open('Results.txt')
    title = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20}'.format('Nickname','Matches Played','Matches Won','Matches Lost','Points')
    print(title)
    for line in myfile:
        item = line.split(',')
        points = int(item[2]) * 3
        if points != 0:
            result = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3} {4:20}'.format(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3],point)
            print(result)
```

So I have been given a file and I am suppose to sort the list in order of highest to lowest by points. To calculate points I will need to do the amount of matches won * 3 and print a sorted list of names and other from top to bottom. Here's the list.

- 1)Leeri,19,7,12
- 2)Jenker,19,8,11
- 3)Tieer,19,0,19
- 5)Baby Boss,19,7,12
- 6)Gamered,19,5,14
- 7)Dogman,19,3,16
- 8)Harlock,19,6,13
- 9)Billies,19,7,12

How do you do it? Do you need like a sorting algorithm?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you google "python sort"? If so, what did you try and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I did google and I have completely no idea how a sort works in python no code I read up I understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
scores = []
myfile = open('Results.txt')
for line in myfile:
    scores.append(line.split(','))

sortedScores  = sorted(scores,key=lambda x: x[2]*3)
```

This will create a `list` of `list` (each sublist is an `item`as you called it), then sort it by the third element, that is the total wins.

Note: 
The `key=lambda x: x[2]*3` is a parameter given to `sorted` to specify sorting criteria. For each item in `scores` the `lambda` function is called. 
The item is a `list`, and we return it's third element multiplied by three, that is the value to sort by.

Answer (score 1):

It' s actually pretty easy:

```
f = open("Results.txt")
title = ("{:20}" * 5).format(
    "Nickname",
    "Matches Played",
    "Matches Won",
    "Matches Lost",
    "Points"
)
print(title)
lines = [i.rstrip().split(',') for i in f]  # this is a generator expression
f.close()
lines.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: int(x[2]) * 3)  # sorts the list
# reverse = reversed order. Python normally sorts from small to high.
print("\n".join('{:20}' * 5).format(*(i + [int(x[2]) * 3])))
# f(*l) calls f with l as its arguments
# (note the plural. so f(*[1, 2, 3]) is the same as f(1, 2, 3))
# list1 + list2 concatenates them.
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help I'm afraid I will need to do more learning to be able to understand obviously I wouldn't just copy and paste I will need to learn only then I can learn :)